# Grey area while plotting inline in Ipython Qt console

Tags: matplotlib, ipython, qtconsole

I have used the Ipython Qtconsole 1.1.0. together with Matplotlib 1.3.1. I want to plot my figures in the Qt-console and I therefore follow the examples from this [page](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/interactive/qtconsole.html). When I follow their instructions I get a grey rectangle around my plot which they don't get. Why does this happen? Does anyone know what their settings are and how can I change my settings to get the same result?

Comment: I guess this is the same issue as already posted here https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/4307?

Comment: I did not find that during my search. Problem solved. Thanks.